# Jest Error - TypeError: this._environment.runScript is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, lwc-jest

Test suite failed to run

TypeError: this._environment.runScript is not a function

```
  at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/@salesforce/lwc-jest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:856:41)
```

Hey, I am keep getting this error when I am trying to test, I have tried everything and I can't resolve it. Could you help?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117593/jest-unit-test-script-fails-with-typeerror-this-environment-runscript-is-not-a) is a similar issue, please have a look might be helpful.